# shutdown and systemctl not found in any directory on Redis (Debian GNU) container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, redis, debian

I'm trying to issue a shutdown command on a redis container. The image I used is `redis`.

I tried all of the following:

```
shutdown -h now
/sbin/shutdown -h now
/bin/shutdown -h now
systemctl poweroff
```

All of them say the command is not found.

OS info: (from `cat /etc/*-release`)

```sh
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Why?  Are you trying to shut down the host from inside a container; and if so, why from inside a Redis container?  (It’d be forbidden unless the container was `--privileged` and even so that’d be really weird.)

Comment: to shut down a container from inside the container, just kill the running process (in this case, redis) or from the host, use `docker stop <containerid>`

Comment: @DavidMaze we are spinning these up in automated tests and if those should fail, or the build process fails, we still want them to shut down so they don't consume resources. Having them shut themselves down solves that.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are using doesn't include these binaries neither should, specially systemctl.

Containers should initialize as fast as possible and having a full featured init system goes again that purpose because of the overhead they impose.

That's why there are smaller init systems being used to deal with containers, like [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini).

Remember that containers are processes that run in the host kernel, so you should be stopping and starting them from the host. Docker has all the utilities necessary to do so.

Comment: `"so you should be stopping and starting them from the host"`
There are always reasons for exceptions. In our case, we are spinning these up in automated tests and if those should fail, or the build process fails, we still want them to shut down so they don't consume resources. Having them shut themselves down solves that.

Comment: The containers running the build process or tests should have them as their main process (via the entrypoint instruction). Your application should throw an exit code 1 and the containers will be shutdown and the resources dealocated.

Answer (score 0):

You clarified in a comment that you're just trying to have the container shut itself down when a test run completes.

You need none of these tools to do that.  A Docker container runs one main process; as soon as that process exits, the container exits too.  In most languages there is some form of `exit()` function that can do this.

As an example, say you have a Python-based application, and you've chosen to build the `pytest` unit-test runner into the image.  You can run a container based on that with

```
docker run --rm myimage pytest
```

which will run `pytest` instead of whatever `CMD` was specified in the image's Dockerfile, and delete the container when the tests finish.

`shutdown` shuts down the *host*.  You can't do this without a `--privileged` container, and even then it would be extremely unusual.  Similarly, `systemctl` interacts with a systemd init process, and it's pretty unusual for a Docker container to run that; you need to go out of your way to keep it from trying to manage a large swath of host- and kernel-oriented things that are already being managed.  Best practice is to run one process in a container, or if you must run multiple, use a very light-weight process manager like supervisord.

Comment: The tests are outside the container. Inside it is redis. So it will have no idea the tests finished.

Comment: As @MrE says in his comment above, just `docker stop` the container then.

Comment: from inside the container? these are automated tests running while no humans are around

Comment: From outside the container; from the same automation you `docker run` it initially.

Comment: right, but what if that automation fails/crashes? then we'll have a bunch of containers running forever. this takes care of that